# Research Assistant badge - text not displayed single line

Tags: support, bug, badges

In the "Select your next badge" page from one's profile, the formatting for the [Research Assistant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant) badge appears to be word-wrapping as opposed to displaying on a single line.

Viewing from mobile phone shows:

[image]

Viewing from desktop working as expected:
[image]

Comment: Related, [the same happens in the Badges section of the user activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372851).